# 500 internal server error when adding many product options in opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, opencart, internal-server-error

Please help me guys, I am just an opencart newbie, i have this error 1 week now.

When I am saving many options in my opencart 2.0.3.1 admin panel's product page i get 500 internal server error. when i view the error logs, i got this lines.

```
2016-03-16 19:03:34 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: points in W:\vhosts\contax4u.com.au\httpdocs\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 131
2016-03-16 19:03:34 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: points in W:\vhosts\contax4u.com.au\httpdocs\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 175
2016-03-16 19:03:34 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: weight in W:\vhosts\contax4u.com.au\httpdocs\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 175
2016-03-16 19:03:34 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: weight_prefix in W:\vhosts\contax4u.com.au\httpdocs\admin\model\catalog\product.php on line 175
```

the error is indicating these lines

line 131:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . (int)$data['tax_class_id'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "',product_type = '" . (int)$data['product_type'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

line 175:

```
foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['product_option_value_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
                    }
```

how can fix this, please help me guys.

Comment: You're not asking a question. Please edit your post to make it one.

Have you looked at the lines 131 and 175 of `product.php` because your log snippet says there are undefined indices `points` and `weight`.

Comment: i just edit my post Mr. Martin Cowie, thanks for checking my post, is that ok now?

Comment: It's improved, though it still lacks focus. Focussed questions get more & better answers that broad questions.

Additionally you've not answered my original point - what you found at the lines referenced in the log file - `product.php` lines 131 and 175.

Comment: is that good Mr. @MartinCowie? if there is any correction let me know. thanks